# It is possible dump MySQL database with query command to XML?

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

It is possible to dump MySQL database programmatically with command or query to XML? Or upload (import) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Utility `mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) has a `--xml` option:

> `--xml`, `-X`
>
> Write dump output as well-formed XML.

Sample command line:

```
> mysqldump --xml mydb > mydb.xml
```

Comment: So, can I use this command like query command "SELECT * FROM"?

Comment: @Sahasrar: no you cannot. This is a command line utility. You might want to have a look at the documentation, which I linked in my answer.

Comment: Ok, i will look on it. But, im looking for way how to do it over C# in program. I had an idea to query all records from all table one by one and writing it to xml folder. However, i would like to find smoother way to do it